# Do not display ... when UILabel too short

Tags: xcode, cocoa, uilabel

I have an UILabel that I would like to make appear from left to right. In order to to this, I increase gradually its width, however in this case the text shows '...' at the end.

How to prevent the '...' to be displayed ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `lineBreakMode` property of UILabel, I think what you want is `NSLineBreakByClipping`